# How to send .aspx page to email body

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I need to send mail by using url.

For example
   My url Like as follows

www.site.com/employee.aspx?EmpCode=12

In employee.aspx i am getting EmpCode from query string and fetch employee profile from db by using listview control.

I need to send this  **www.site.com/employee.aspx?EmpCode=12** url data as email body.

```
  public static void sendmail(String url,String to,String subject)
    {
        string from = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromemail"];
        string password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailpassword"];

        MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(to);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(from, "EMP PROFILE", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.Body = GetPage(url);
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, password);
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here i am using webrequest to read data from url as follows

```
 protected static string GetPage(string url)
    {
        WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

But it shows an error like as

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I need to send employee profile to email. How to Solve it

Comment: Are you trying to build the world's most unsecure site?

Comment: Create an email template which uses the same _data_, not the same _code_

Comment: Do your employer a favor and read this: https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/